# Are the eigenvectors of an image the same, even if the object inside the image change location?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I have a curious question.

I have two images.

Picture 1:

[image]

And picture 2:

[image]

If I create the eigenvectors of each image by using MATLAB code. Here I'm using Singular Value Decomposition.

```
>> pic2 = rgb2gray(imread('pic2.bmp'));
>> pic1 = rgb2gray(imread('pic1.bmp'));
>> [U2, E2, V2] = svd(double(pic2));
>> [U1, E1, V1] = svd(double(pic1));
```

Then I plot them using scatter plot

```
>> scatter(U1(:, 1), U1(:, 2))
>> hold on
>> scatter(U2(:, 1), U2(:, 2))
>> grid on
>> legend('Pic1', 'Pic2')
```

It's seems to be no difference at all. 100% the same.

[image]

**Question:**

Does that mean that eigenvectors remains exactly the same, no mather of the location of the image? So if the red dot would be in a different location, the eigenvectors will still be the same as long the shape is the same? That also means I cannot compute the location of the red dot, if the eigenvectors are the same?

Comment: Worth noting that fhe association between an image and a matrix is logically dubious. In particular, a matrix has eigenvalues only if it is square, but there is nothing about images that mathematically "prefers" square images. It is an essentially artificial relationship in that the two are arrays of data. That doesn't mean it isn't useful, ever, just that it is of dubious mathematical value.

Comment: @Thomas: fortunately the SVD doesn't have this problem, which is what the OP actually computes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked about the eigenvectors but you've computed the SVD; these are not the same thing! The SVD is invariant under permuting either rows or columns, while this is quite false for the eigendecomposition. That's why it has this behavior: you can get from one image to the other by permuting some rows, then permuting some columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I want to do PCA...I cannot use SVD?

Comment: PCA and SVD are roughly the same thing, they're just not the same thing as the eigendecomposition.

Comment: Ok! So what I just did, was PCA.

Comment: But why did they not differ? Should I try with other rows of $U1$ and $U2$?

Comment: That is exactly the content of my answer: the SVD is invariant under permuting either rows or columns (in the sense that you get the same left and right singular vectors, just in a different order).

Comment: I can see now when I compare $U1(:, 1)$ and $U1(:, 5)$ against $U2(:, 1)$ and $U2(:, 5)$, it become a difference. But not between $U1(:, 1)$ and $U1(:, 2)$ and $U2(:, 1)$ and $U2(:, 2)$. I guess I can compute the difference between these two images then?

Comment: Yes, they would be different if you also kept track of the order of the singular vectors, or equivalently kept track of which singular values they paired with.

Comment: Great! Is there any way I can reconstruct the image by excluding some rows?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The SVD factors your matrix as the product of three other matrices, so you can reconstruct the original matrix exactly by computing this product.

Comment: Oh! Yes. I forgot! [U, E, V] = svd(A), then A = U*E*V!

Comment: One quick question! If I want to compute SVD in the fastest way...should I use Jacobi Rotation for SVD then? It requries square matrices, but that's OK.

Comment: I have no idea, I'm not familiar with the computational aspects here at all, sorry.